# Run time Error 1004 when calling function inside of a For Each loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that finds any bold words within a specific range. This function is called in the for each loop below. The way it's currently set up it returns true if bold words exist anywhere in the range, or false if no bold words exist in the range. What I want to do is get it so it stops when it finds the bold words so I can do some other actions, then continue on down the list. I was thinking of doing something along these lines, however it throws an error on the second line

```
dim i as range
set i = range("C11:C6000")    

for each i in range("C11:C6000")
    FindBoldCharacters(Range(i))   'throws "run time error 1004 application or object defined error" here
        if i = true then
            'do some stuff here'

        else

        end if

        next i
```

here is the function that the piece of code is calling

```
Function FindBoldCharacters(ByVal aCell As Range) As Boolean
    FindBoldCharacters = IsNull(aCell.Font.Bold)
    If Not FindBoldCharacters Then FindBoldCharacters = aCell.Font.Bold
End Function
```

The function works when just called by itself, but doesn't work when I try to call it in this way. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: what is I dimmed as?

Comment: The way you are looping through your `For...Each` indicates `i` is likely a `Variant\Range` (unless you explicitly declare it as a range or something else earlier in other code).  `Range(i))` is meaningless.  Try just passing in `i` like so: `FindBoldCharacters(i)`.  You then attempt to use `i` as a Boolean.  Additionally your loop syntax is off, there should only be one `Next i`, not two like you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment there are a couple of things off with your code as is.

- The variable `i`, if undeclared prior to this loop, will be dimensioned at run time as a `Range` object, not as a string holding the cell address as you appear to be using it as
- Related, `i` is later being used as a `Boolean` when it is a `Range` object
- Each `For..` should only have one `Next`, your code will throw a `Next without For` error if you try to run it

First, declare `i` as a `Range` object, and then pass it into your function like so `FindBoldCharacters(i)` (this makes sense as in your function declaration you say you are expecting `aCell` as a `Range`)

Second, evaluate the function directly in the `If` statement

Finally, move the `Next i` from inside the `If` statement outside.

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
        Dim i As Range

        For Each i In Range("C11:C6000")
                If FindBoldCharacters(i) = True Then
                    'do some stuff here'
                Else

                End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem!  Happy coding :)